# connector list does not show my installed connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Good day,

Base on https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/index.html#installing-jdbc-drivers ,
I use the following command to isntall the jdbc connector:

```
confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
```

Command run successfully, I can see `confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc` folder is created under `<confluent-plaform>/share/confluent-hub-components`.

And here is the screen shot to show the result of my install command:
[image]

After that, I following the next instruction, to upload the jdbc drivers jar file to `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`.
[image]

After that, I come to https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/index.html , to load the db connector, first step, I use the list command to list down the connector I have by using following command:

```
confluent local services connect connector list
```

The output is show as follow:

```
[meow@localhost confluent-7.0.1]$ confluent local services connect connector list
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Bundled Connectors:
  file-sink
  file-source
  replicator
```

There is no connector name `jdbc-source` in the list, thus, I cant proceed to the next step to continue.

May I know what mistake on my steps?

Comment: Why do you need to list anything? As answered before, make sure you are editing the correct config files, then just load the connector config... Also, your image is cut off, there's no kafka connect jars in that folder

Answer (score 0):

After running `confluent-hub install` you must restart the Kafka Connect worker for it to pick up the new connector.

Since you're using the Confluent CLI the commands are:

- [`confluent local services connect stop`](https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/local/services/connect/confluent_local_services_connect_stop.html)
- [`confluent local services connect start`](https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/local/services/connect/confluent_local_services_connect_start.html)

---

*Edit*: your screenshot shows that you told the Confluent Hub client **not** to update any of the Kafka Connect worker configurations. Therefore the worker will not pick up the connector that you've installed.

You should run the Confluent Hub client again and tell it to update the Kafka Connect worker configurations when prompted, and then restart the Kafka Connect worker. After that it will pick up the new connector.

Comment: Hi @Robin, ya, actually I did. I restart it then only go for the list command, but still the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the execution and output of the `confluent-hub install` command please

Comment: The image shows that the connector was downloaded, or at least there's a folder there

Comment: The Confluent Hub client should also patch the Kafka Connect config file for `plugin.path`

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, sory for late reply. I just attached the screen shot. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @RobinMoffatt, May I know is it just run `confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest` again? If yes, I did actually, and when I do connector list, the connector still not showing.

Comment: did you restart the worker?